# Failed to notify project evaluation listener, for react-native-maps

Tags: javascript, genymotion, react-native, react-native-maps

I am getting error whenever I tried to run a project which has for react-native-maps. Otherwise it is working fine incase no react-native-maps, I am using Geneymotion as my android emaultor. Please suggest me on the same. Please find attached screenshots.

[Reactive native run android result: react-native run-android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnzX0.png)

[Geneymotion Emulator Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khaPn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to download required sdk 23

Comment: Thanks for your comments :)